# Does there necessary exist a base of a vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces

Given a vector space $V$, does there necessary exist a set $S$ of vectors from $V$ such that $S$ is a base of $V$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you assume the axiom of choice, you can prove that every vector space has a basis.

http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Vector_Space_has_Basis

Edit: Vadim makes a good point in the comments and I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Not everyone accepts the axiom of choice, so I think "yes" is rather misleading.

Comment: @vadim123, that's a good point, I've edited it.

Comment: In fact, within $\bf ZF$, the statement "Every vector space has a basis" is equivalent to Axiom of Choice itself. 
For a proof, look at $\S 4.4$ of Horst Herrlich's book  ***Axoim of Choice*** (ISBN 0075-8434).

Comment: If $V$ is finitely generated then you can avoid the axiom of choice using Gaussian elimination to reduce a generating set to a basis.